# React Hook useEffect with useCallback infinite loop with function as a dependency (react-table v7)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I can't wrap my head around this React Hooks example. I have a prop call `sortBy` coming through to a component. Based on that, I want to update (react-table v7: `^7.0.0-rc.10` ) table sort. It's calling `toggleSortBy` (comes from the library). When this runs, it ends up in an infinite loop.

When I take out `toggleSortBy`, everything works but I get the error:

`React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'toggleSortBy'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

I've hit upon this a few times, so I guess I don't understand something fundamental.

```
  //const sortBy = [{
  // id: 'test',
  // desc: true
  //}]

  const doSort = useCallback(() => {
    toggleSortBy(sortBy[0].id, sortBy[0].desc, false);
  }, [sortBy, toggleSortBy]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(sortBy.length) {
      doSort();
    }
  }, [sortBy, doSort]);
```

How do I get this code to work without infinite looping or producing a lint error?

Comment: Where toggleSortBy is defined?

Comment: Coming from react-table library

Comment: There was a bug, which was fixed last month only. You are using latest version of react-table?

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a link to the bug? Codebase version is `^7.0.0-rc.10`

Comment: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1608

Comment: I update to `^7.0.0-rc.11`... the same results occur

Comment: What happens if you put the toggleSortBy call directly in the useEffect hook? I don't think the useCallback is making sense, because you already limiting when it should be called, right?

Comment: You get the same result. Infinite loop on adding toggleSortBy as a dependency

Comment: What happens if wrap toggleSortBy in a separate function outside the render function and use that as a dependency?

Comment: show toggleSortBy func

Comment: I created an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-framework-b5sxq. In the console you'll see the waring: `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`